# Positioning on javascript DOM with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, dom, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm planning to create a dynamic textbox that will be divided into two rows equally downwards even on the odd count of textbox_value but having trouble on my code.

**MY EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

[image]

I need to have Reading 1 and Reading 5 on same row as well as
Reading 2 and Reading 6 on same row
Reading 3 and Reading 7 on same row
Reading 4 alone on one row.

**ACCUMULATED OUTPUT ON MY CODE:**
[image]

It looks like textboxes Reading 5,6 and 7 are positioned with the same row as Reading 4.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
var textbox_value = 7;

for (var count = 1; count <= Math.round(textbox_value/2); count++){
        var childdiv = document.createElement("div");
        childdiv.className = "row";
        var textboxdiv = document.createElement("div");
        textboxdiv.className = "col-md-6";
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.innerHTML = display+' '+count;
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.id = textbox_group+count;
        input.className = "form-control circle";
        input.type = "text";
        input.setAttribute("placeholder", display+' '+count);
        input.setAttribute("ng-model", "field."+textbox_group+"["+count+"]");
        input.setAttribute("onkeypress","ValidationNum('"+textbox_group+count+"',$(this).val())");
        input.setAttribute("onkeyup", "get_meter_data_capture('onclick','"+special_meter_tag+"')");


        textboxdiv.appendChild(label);
        textboxdiv.appendChild(input);
        childdiv.appendChild(textboxdiv);
        parentdiv.appendChild(childdiv);
    }

  for (var count2 = Math.round(textbox_value/2)+1; count2 <= textbox_value; count2++){
        var textboxdiv2 = document.createElement("div");
        textboxdiv2.className = "col-md-6"
        var label2 = document.createElement("label");
        label2.innerHTML = display+' '+count2;
        var input2 = document.createElement("input");
        input2.id = textbox_group+count2;
        input2.className = "form-control circle";
        input2.type = "text";
        input2.setAttribute("placeholder", display+' '+count2);
        input2.setAttribute("ng-model", "field."+textbox_group+"["+count2+"]");
        input2.setAttribute("onkeypress","ValidationNum('"+textbox_group+count2+"',$(this).val())");
        input2.setAttribute("onkeyup", "get_meter_data_capture('onclick','"+special_meter_tag+"')");


        textboxdiv2.appendChild(label2);
        textboxdiv2.appendChild(input2);
        childdiv.appendChild(textboxdiv2);
        parentdiv.appendChild(childdiv);
    }
```

Comment: Using your words, what is your issue? Are you sure you need to include all of that code in the question?

Comment: the issue is im not getting the result and I'm confused on how to acquire my expected result. I maybe have done something wrong with my code

Comment: _Break down the problem into smaller ones_. I feel this is too large to solve in one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can create a row first, then 2 columns and add ur textboxes to these columns like

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col">
for(var i=1;i<=count/2;i++){
<div> ur label and textbox </div>
}
</div> end of first column

<div class="col">
for(var i=count/2+1;i<=count;i++) {
<div> ur label and textbox </div>
}
</div> end of second column

<div> end of row
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes this is the logic but I have to stick with my coding format.